# laravel helper class are not being called

Tags: php, laravel

Inside my app folder, I have following file structure.

- console
- Exceptions
- Helpers
- Http

Inside Helpers folder, I have a Helpers.php file that consists following code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper 
{
    public static function shout($string)
    {
        return strtoupper($string);
    }
}
```

From Controller inside http

I try to call this helper function using following code

```
Helper::shout($test);
```

But I am getting error

```
Class 'App\Helpers\Helper' not found
```

Actually this was working fine in my laravel 5.4 version. Now I am using this class in new version laravel.

Can anybody help me what should I do in new version laravel?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your `composer.json` where are located your helper class.

In your case:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helpers.php"
    ],
},
```

For more information you can read [this](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers).

Also you can try like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper 
{
    public function run($string)
    {
        return strtoupper($string);
    }

    public static function shout($string)
    {
        $instance = new self;
        $instance->run($string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankx I didnot knew I have to include it there. But I have many helper files. So do i need to include all those helper files inside autoload?

Comment: I m not sure. But did is this work when you include like this?

Comment: So problem is solved. Check update and also try like this. Good luck!

Comment: @user1687891 Did you try without including with second solution?

Answer (score -1):

Once include ;

```
require_once ROOT . '/helpers.php';
```

And edit composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helpers.php"
    ],
},
```

Finally;

```
composer dump-autoload
```